# Can someone walk me through this problem step by step-Symmetric Pairs problem

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please help a beginner understand the process for solving this in MS SQL Server. If you have any courses you would recommend that would be great as well. I have taken some but they have not equipped me to solve this. I am a beginner. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As phrased, your question is not a good fit for this site. Please read [ask]. Good questions here identify a specific programming problem that can be solved with a specific answer. I would start by Googling "SQL Symmetric Pairs Problem".

Comment: Please, we need to see what you tried - the SQL query you attempted

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to perform some kind of joining your data to itself (also called self join) in order to be able to check for the given condition:

```
x1 = y2 and x2 = y1
```

We can use the following query to get all pairs:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [x] INT
   ,[y] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([x], [y])
VALUES (20, 20)
      ,(20, 20)
      ,(20, 21)
      ,(23, 22)
      ,(22, 23)
      ,(21, 20);


WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [x]
          ,[y]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [RowID]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[x] = DS2.[y]
    AND DS1.[y] = DS2.[x]
WHERE DS1.[RowID] <> DS2.[RowID];
```

[image]

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we are generating a unique ID for each row in order to be sure it won't be joined to itself.

In your sample result, you have only the first part of the pair (where `x1 < x2` and you get unique values. So, we can change the query a little bit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [x]
               ,[y]
FROM @DataSource DS1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @DataSource DS2
    WHERE DS1.[x] = DS2.[y]
        AND DS1.[y] = DS2.[x]
        AND DS1.[X] <= DS2.[x]
)
ORDER BY [x];
```

[image]

It has one small change. We are looking for the part of the pair, where `x1<x2`. And of course, if you are more comfortable with joins you can just do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DS1.[x]
               ,DS1.[y]
FROM @DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN @DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[x] = DS2.[y]
    AND DS1.[y] = DS2.[x]
    AND DS1.[x] <= DS2.[x]
ORDER BY DS1.[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Case 1: Cases where x=y and have more than one record */
with tempa as
(
    select x,y
    from functions
    where x=y
    group by x,y
    having count(*)>=2
),
/* Case 2: Where x=y and y=x and x<>y */
tempb as
(
  select distinct A_X,A_Y from
    (
        select distinct a.x as A_X,a.y as A_Y, b.y as B_Y,b.x as B_X
        from functions a inner join functions b
        on a.x=b.y and a.y=b.x
    ) 
   where A_X<B_X
)
select * from 
(
    select * from tempa
    union 
    select * from tempb
)
 order by 1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Here I have considered  2 cases:   Case 1: If X and Y are equal, they must be having atleast 2 entries in the table, and I have considered these cases in the table tempa. Case 2: If x1=y2 and y1=x2, Eg: 1,2 and 2,1 then we need to consider only 1,2 and exclude 2,1. These cases are considered in the table tempb. Finally, I am doing a union of Case 1 and case 2 and sort this result by x. I hope this explanation makes your understanding easier.

Answer (score 0):

/*In this case, x1 = y1 and x2 = y2 s.t. (x1 = y2) = (x2 = y1) The x1, y1 pairs are at least duplicated (2x)*/

```
(SELECT x,
        y
 FROM   functions
 GROUP  BY 1,
           2
 HAVING Count(*) >= 2)
```

/*Union with*/

```
UNION ALL
```

/*This case, (x1 < y1; use where, naturally excludes x1 = y1 above) and (x1 = y2 and x2 = y1; use join on)*/

```
(SELECT a.x,
        a.y
 FROM   functions a
        join functions b
          ON a.x = b.y
             AND a.y = b.x
 WHERE  a.x < a.y)
ORDER  BY x
```

Answer (score -1):

````
WHERE f1.X = f1.Y AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Functions WHERE X = f1.X AND Y = f1.Y) > 1

UNION

SELECT f1.X, f1.Y from Functions f1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT X, Y FROM Functions WHERE f1.X = Y 
             AND f1.Y = X AND f1.X < X)
ORDER BY X;```
````

Comment: FYR "Can someone walk me through this problem step by step"